# Why the generated assembler of certain boolean expressions contains a conditional jump?

Tags: c++, compilation, logical-operators, operator-precedence, boolean-expression

Consider this code:

```
bool res_true();
bool res_false();

bool test1(const bool cond)
{
    return (cond && res_true()) || (!cond && res_false());
}

bool test2(const bool cond)
{
    return cond ? res_true() : res_false();
}
```

Both `test1()` and `test2()` select a certain boolean result between `res_true(),res_false()` basing on a boolean input `cond`.
I know that c++ compilers nowadays can be pretty smart, but I usually tended to use the `test1()` form -despite less readable- because in my naivety I thought that in that case there were just logic boolean operations, with no conditional jumps; they are bad, right?
Well today I tried that in [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xrdKjanvq) and saw that the generated output is very similar for both the functions: `test1()` contains a conditional jump (*moreover, depending on compiler and enabled optimizations, the generated assembler of `test1()` can be worst than the one of `test2()`*), why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the default c++ boolean operators `||` and `&&` are short-circuited (with guaranteed left-to-right evaluation), so a logical expression may or may not be fully evaluated depending on the results of his sub-expressions.
for example in:

```
f() || g()
```

`f()` will be called first and `g()` won't be called if `f()` was `true`; similarly in:

```
f() && g()
```

`g()` won't be called if `f()` was `false`, so the generated assembler must contain a conditional jump to ensure to short-circuit the expression.